# Changing Font type in dynamic ranges over multiple worksheets

Tags: vba

I'm trying to create a loop to change the font type and font color based on text in the cells in 3 worksheets, each with a named dynamic range.  I cannot select all of the cells on the worksheets because I have a legend in cells above the range.

I have successfully formatted each range separately, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way. I understand that Range will not work on more than one worksheet. I tried to use Collection and Array with the named ranges. I clearly don't understand how to use these, because neither worked.

I've been attempting to figure this out for a week. I've read so many posts, but most of them are attempting a function over a defined range in the worksheets. I'm very new to VBA (all coding)  and this is the closest that I have come.

This is what has worked.

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim daily As Worksheet, mon As Worksheet, per As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range
Dim d1 As Range, m1 As Range, p1 As Range

Set daily = Sheets("Daily")
Set mon = Sheets("Monthly")
Set per = Sheets("Personnel")
Set d1 = daily.Range(("A7"), daily.Range("A7").End(xlUp) _
   .Offset(-1, 46))
Set m1 = mon.Range("A6:Y6")
Set p1 = per.Range(("A4"), per.Range("A4").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 20))

With d1
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="T"
    Cells.Replace What:="Incomplete", Replacement:="T"
    Cells.Replace What:="Complete", Replacement:="R"
    Cells.Replace What:="Not Applicable", Replacement:="x"
End With

d1.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

For Each cell In d1
    If cell.Value = "T" Then
        cell.Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
    ElseIf cell.Value = "R" Then
        cell.Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
    ElseIf cell.Value = "x" Then
        cell.Font.Name = "Webdings"
    ElseIf cell.Value = "v" Then
        cell.Font.Name = "Wingdings"
    End If
Next

With d1
.Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
End With

' this is repeated for m1 and then p1
End Sub
```

This did not

```
Set dta_all = Array(Sheets("Daily").daily.Range(("A7"), _ 
        daily.Range("A7").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 46)), _
        Sheets("Monthly").Range("A6:Y6"), _
       Sheets("Personnel").Range(("A4"), _
        per.Range("A4").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 20)))

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each cell In dta_all
        If cell.Text = "Incomplete" Then
            cell.Value = "T"
            cell.Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
            cell.Font.Bold = True
            cell.Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I get a 438 error- Property or method not supported. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: What line is giving you that error?  And have you considered conditional formatting?

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all I would like to say that most beginners abuse the use of `.Select`, and you are not, and obviously trying a better way. For this, well done! One of the first corrections I would like to point out is the use of `With` statement, you need to use `.` in order to actually work, i.e.: `With d1 cells...` should be `With d1 .cells....`

Comment: My very first attempt was to conditionally format, but I was having problems changing the font name. DarXyde's correction makes more sense than my repeating cell with each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the common/repeated parts of your code:

```
With d1
    .Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="T"
    'etc
End With

d1.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

For Each cell In d1
   'etc
Next

With d1
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
    'etc
End With
```

What you can do is to create a separate sub containing only those parts, which takes a Range as an argument:

```
Sub ApplyFormat(rng As Range)
    With rng
        .Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="T"
        'etc
    End With

    rng.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
       'etc
    Next

    With rng
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
        'etc
    End With
End sub
```

...and then call if from your main code:

```
ApplyFormat d1
ApplyFormat m1
ApplyFormat p1
```

Whenever you find yourself writing the same set of lines more than once, it may be a good candidate for factoring out into a separate sub: identify the variable part(s) and make them parameters in the Sub or Function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there had to be a better way than repeating myself. Am I correct that the only time I will need to specifically state the sheet name is when I set the variable?

Comment: Yes - a Range object is always linked to a specific worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of ranges (i`ve never tried before, but seems a neat option to keep in mind). Reusing your code, and also as Tim suggested, I've made a sample how to do it, please see below:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Macro3()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim daily As Worksheet, mon As Worksheet, per As Worksheet

Set daily = wb.Sheets("Daily")
Set mon = wb.Sheets("Monthly")
Set per = wb.Sheets("Personnel")

'Take the ranges into an array of ranges
Dim arrRanges(1 To 3) As Range   'add more as needed

'Set each element of the array as you would have with normal variables
Set arrRanges(1) = daily.Range(("A7"), daily.Range("A7").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 46)) 'd1
Set arrRanges(2) = mon.Range("A6:Y6") 'm1
Set arrRanges(3) = per.Range(("A4"), per.Range("A4").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 20)) 'p1

Dim R As Long, C As Long, X As Long

'Now you can loop through
    For X = LBound(arrRanges) To UBound(arrRanges)  'For each of the ranges
        For R = 2 To arrRanges(X).Rows.Count    'For each row in each range - except headers
            For C = 1 To arrRanges(X).Columns.Count 'For each column in each range
                'Debug.Print arrRanges(X).Cells(R, C).Address 'for debuging purposes
                With arrRanges(X)
                    .Cells(R, C).Value = setReplacements(.Cells(R, C).Value)
                    Call setFont(.Cells(R, C))
                End With
            Next C
        Next R

        With arrRanges(X).Offset(1, 0)
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter 'align everything except headers
            Call setBorders(.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)) 'set borders to everything except headers
        End With
    Next X

End Sub

Function setReplacements(str As String)
'Set the replacements here
    Select Case str
        Case "", "Incomplete"
            setReplacements = "T"
        Case "Complete"
            setReplacements = "R"
        Case "Not Applicable"
            setReplacements = "x"
        Case Else
            'do something here
            setReplacements = "T" 'assume incomplete for any other value?
    End Select
End Function

Sub setFont(rng As Range)
'Set your other formatting here
    Select Case rng.Value
        Case "T", "R"
            rng.Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
        Case "x"
            rng.Font.Name = "Webdings"
        Case "v"
            rng.Font.Name = "Wingdings"
    End Select
End Sub

Sub setBorders(rng As Range)
'Set your borders here
    With rng
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlMedium
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
    End With
End Sub
```

One thing to keep in mind... looping over the sheet is never a great idea, especially if you have a large number of rows. Unfortunately when it comes to formatting is not a lot you can do, but that. For general data however, is best to load your data in an array, do your transforms, then spit it out again... the less you interact with the sheets, the faster it runs.

Comment: DarXyde Thank you!! While I have been working hard to avoid Select, I haven't been setting up the Subs correctly. I've had all my code in one (Gasp!) Your comments have given me clarity. I tried the sample, but the column headers change. I suspect I have something off with my ranges. I will experiment some more.

Comment: If you dont want to include headers in formatting/replacing/etc, start the loop at the next row, i.e.: `For R = 2 To arrRanges(X).Rows.Count`

Comment: See updated answer for how you can manipulate the range size, and apply formatting to everything except headers.